# R: grep drop all columns even when its not matching

Tags: r

Trying to remove columns from a large data frame. Using `grep` and it works fine when actually there are matching columns. But when there is zero matching columns it drops all the columns.

`s <- s[, -grep("^Test", colnames(s))]`

To confirm that there are no columns that match `Test`

```
> y <- grep("^Test", colnames(s))
> y
integer(0)
```

What is exactly going on here?

Comment: so that's `s[,-0]` then? Try `mtcars[,-1]` then `mtcars[,-0]` or even `mtcars[,0]` which is surely the same?

Comment: ps check `grepl` command instead...

Comment: tried grepl instead of grep same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `grepl` and `!` instead.

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID =c(1,2,3), T = c("words", "stuff","things"))

df2[,!grepl("^Test", colnames(df2))]

  ID      T
1  1  words
2  2  stuff
3  3 things
```

`-grep()` or `-grepl()` return `integer(0)` when there isn't a match.

`-TRUE == -1` where as `!TRUE == FALSE`

Using `!grepl()` returns the full logical vector (`TRUE TRUE`) for each column header, allowing you to correctly subset when no columns meet the condition. In other words for `colname(df)[i]`, `grepl(..., colnames(df))[i]` returns `TRUE` where your pattern is matched, then using `!` you invert to keep the values that don't match, and remove the ones that do.